# How to "reset" VSCode's pytest side panel?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I'm loving TDD, and the python (pytest) sidebar in VSCode is awesome for this.  However, it's not super resilient.

Over time, while developing, of course one cycles in a loop of adding new code, making mistakes, fixing them, and testing.

VSCode (or pytest, not sure) will *eventually* choke up and stop working, after I've made enough errors.  Even when the errors are all fixed, the UI won't recover.  Eventually, the UI stops responding - the little refresh animated gifs no longer work, the tree doesn't update, and you can't run tests in the sidebar any more.

A restart of the whole IDE *always* fixed this, and I'm g2g for another 20m or so until it hoses up again.

*Is there a way to easily "reset" the Testing sidebar/subsystem when it chokes, without having to shut down entirely?*

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you have a look at the 'Python Test Log', 'Python Language Server', and the 'Python' Channel in the OUTPUT pannel? And could you provide a screenshot of it?

Comment: thanks for the tips, will update next time it hoses up

Comment: the logs are all normal.  As I said, the problem is 100% in the UI manifestation of the underlying pytest.  The tests still work - it's the side panel view on those tests that's getting hosed.  Is this part of a "plugin" to VSCode, and how to troubleshoot that?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. Could you Click this: Help -> Toggle Developer Tools and check the errors in the  Console panel?

Comment: Does the command of 'Python: Run All Tests' work?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your problem, If both of the above methods do not work, could you submit a bug in the [VSCode python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues?q=test+panel+block) Github?

Comment: yes the commands continue to work.  The only evident failure is the UI in the side panel - the visual experience seems to lose its connection to the underlying scripts.  Hence the original question - is there a way to reset the sidebar?

Comment: Could you submit a bug in [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues)? Thanks a lot.